# Is it possible to calculate an integral within a layer with tensorflow?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

Is it possible to compute an integral within a layer in tensorflow and tensorflow probability? I have a simple MLP with a couple of dense layers and a concat layer.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow_probability as tfp
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout,Concatenate
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
    
    tfd = tfp.distributions
    
    def create_nn_model():
        inputs = Input(shape=(1,),name="input layer")
        hidden = Dense(50,activation="relu")(inputs)
        hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
        hidden = Dense(50,activation="relu")(hidden)
        hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
        params_mc = Dense(2,activation="relu")(hidden)
        concat= Concatenate(axis=-1)([params_mc, inputs])

        ### speciallayergoeshere
    
        model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=params_mc )
        return model
```

i would like to create a special layer where ,among the other things, there are these random  variables  defined through tensorflow probability (6 trainable parameters :3 means + 3 std)

```py
    alpha1 =tfd.Normal(loc=tf.Variable(-1., name='loc'),scale=tf.Variable(1., name='scale'))
    alpha2 =tfd.Normal(loc=tf.Variable(0., name='loc2'),scale=tf.Variable(2., name='scale'))
    alpha3 =tfd.Normal(loc=tf.Variable(0.3, name='loc3'),scale=tf.Variable(1., name='scale3'))
```

and I need to compute the residual.

$$ \text{res} =u(x) - \int_0^x\frac{1}{(1-\alpha_3)(1+x)^3+\alpha_3e^{ \int_0^{x}\frac{1+ \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 *x}{1+x}  dx}}dx$$

`u(x)` is `concat[:,0]` while  `x` is the input of the network and it is given by `concat[:,1]`.

Is it possible something like this? If yes, how should I update the gradients?

Comment: Integrals within networks are pretty much doable, look into NeuralODEs for example. Howeer, your integral has an analytical solution. You could use that instead

Comment: @Firebug in truth the true integral is more complicated and it's a double integral andI Don t know if there is an analytical solution. But putting this aspect aside, I do not know how to implement the process of updating the gradients for the alpha when there is an integral involved. I did not find any example. I have given a look at neural odes but those are differential equation while mine is not.

Comment: Differential equations can be solved numerically, and that involves solving (or approximating) integrals

Comment: You should check if your double integral has an analytical solution first, because that would be the easiest and probably most efficient

Comment: @Firebug I have tried with Mathematica but as an output it gives me  the same symbolic form with the symbol of integration. I have updated the first message with a better example of the equation.

Comment: Just to clarify notation: this is not what people usually mean when they say "double integral"